# Facebook API: Access Without Reauthentication

Tags: facebook

We're hoping to create mobile phone applications for (among other features) posting video to a user's FaceBook page.  However, using their API, it looks like we would need to open a web viewer and have the user enter their login credentials every time the application is used.  We would prefer to store these credentials so the user only has to login once.

We could of course save the http login post and resend it as needed, but this breaks if FaceBook changes their API and I worry about their terms of service and using an unofficial hack such as this.

Maybe someone knows of another application that uses Facebook this way?

Comment: I don't think that using this is unofficial or a hack

Answer (score 1):

You should have been returned an [oAuth token](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) to use.

The new Facebook API has a service you can call with the old tokens and it returns you a new oAuth token.

Comment: Doesn't the oAuth token have a short expiration time, and requires resubmission of the username/password to get another one?

Comment: I actually have no idea what the timeout is. I was working on an app last week that has old legacy fb auth secret tokens in the db (taken from the cookies I guess). The new fb api has a service you can call with the old tokens and it returns you a new oAuth token.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add offline_access to your permissions. You do this by adding &scope=offline_permissions at the end of your authorization url. Then your oAuth token won't expire.